# Array index out of bounds, using multi dimensional array as a game board

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bounds

This code will check each cell in a 12x12 grid to see if their value can spread or move. x is a standard floor tile, P is the player and I is the infection. The infection can duplicate itself to any adjacent tile whilst the player obviously moves from tile to tile. For some reason I keep getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 error whenever I get to a certain number of turns.

Any ideas? (please save tweaking code til after the problem is fixed guys, thanks. :)

```
public static void tileMovement(char t, int i, int j) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dir = rand.nextInt(3);

        //System.out.println(t);
        if(t == 'x') {
        }
        else if(t == 'I') {
            double chance = Math.random();
            //System.out.println(chance);
            if(chance < 0.35) {
                myGrid[i][j] = t;
                switch(dir) {
                    case 0:
                        if(myGrid[i-1][j] == 'x'||i != 1){
                            myGrid[i-1][j] = t;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        if(myGrid[i+1][j] == 'x'||i != 11){
                            myGrid[i+1][j] = t;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        if(myGrid[i][j-1] == 'x'||j != 1){
                            myGrid[i][j-1] = t;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        if(myGrid[i][j+1] == 'x'||j != 11){
                            myGrid[i][j+1] = t;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(t == 'P'){
            myGrid[i][j] = 'x';                         // j = sideways, i = vertical
            switch(dir) {
                    case 0:
                            if(myGrid[i-1][j] == 'x'||myGrid[i-1][j] == 'I'||i != 1){
                                myGrid[i-1][j] = t;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                break;
                            }
                    case 1:
                            if(myGrid[i+1][j] == 'x'||myGrid[i+1][j] == 'I'||i != 11){
                                myGrid[i+1][j] = t;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                break;
                            }
                    case 2:
                            if(myGrid[i][j-1] == 'x'||myGrid[i][j-1] == 'I'||j != 1){
                                myGrid[i][j-1] = t;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                break;
                            }
                    case 3:
                            if(myGrid[i][j+1] == 'x'||myGrid[i][j+1] == 'I'||j != 11){
                                myGrid[i][j+1] = t;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                break;
                            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly determining the edge of the board.  Here's one of your lines:

```
if(myGrid[i-1][j] == 'x'||i != 1){
```

First, indices start at 0.  Second, check if you are on the left edge first before attempting to access the array.  Do this by taking advantage of "short circuit" evaluation:

```
if (i != 0 && myGrid[i - 1][j] == 'x') {
```

Here, if `i` is `0`, then the condition is `false` and `myGrid[i - 1][j] == 'x'` is never evaluated, and it doesn't have a chance to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can change your other conditions similarly.  You were correct about 11 being the max here.

Incidentally, in each case, you generally `break` in both cases of your `if` condition, and the `else` does nothing but `break`.  It looks more readable and more concise to just `break` outside the `if`:

```
if (condition) {
    // perform operation
}
break;
```

Comment: Arghhhh, I thought I had it right but didn't check. It was originally 0 and then I changed it because I got a one-time error that was actually because of another bit of code.. Thank you though!